# Retain cycle between class and struct

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, retain-cycle

Assuming I have following code:

```
struct X {
    let propertyOfTypeY: Y
}

class Y {
    var propertyOfTypeX: X?
}

let y = Y()
let x = X(propertyOfTypeY: y)
y.propertyOfTypeX = x
```

If these were both classes, then it would mean a retain cycle. However it's not clear to me how the differences between classes and structs apply to the example above. Will it cause a retain cycle, or is it a safe code because of the usage of struct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you have a retain cycle.

```
y.propertyOfTypeX = x
```

copies the value `x` to `y.propertyOfTypeX`, including the
property `x.propertyOfTypeY` which is a reference to `y`.

Therefore

```
y.propertyOfTypeX?.propertyOfTypeY === y
```

holds. What you have is essentially the same as

```
class Y {
    var propertyOfTypeY: Y?
}

var y = Y()
y.propertyOfTypeY = y
```

only that `propertyOfTypeY` is part of a `struct X`
(and that `x` holds an additional reference to `y`).

Comment: Might be useful to note 'struct X { unowned let propertyOfTypeY: Y }' will allow cycle to be broken.

Answer (score 10):

TL;DR There's a retain cycle, but you can see it for **yourself**!

```
struct X {
    let propertyOfTypeY: Y
}

class Y {
    var propertyOfTypeX: X?

    deinit {
        print("I was deinit'ed")
    }
}

do {
    let y = Y()
    let x = X(propertyOfTypeY: y)
    y.propertyOfTypeX = x
}
// y and x should be dealloc'ed here, because the "do scope" ends
```

Comment out `y.propertyOfTypeX = x` and `I was deinit'ed` will be printed, But if you do that assignment, `deinit` is never called.

Same thing can happen if you use a closure.

Comment: A similar "trick" is to put the code inside a `do {  ... }` block and check if deinit is called after  executing the block. That works even with non-optionals.

Answer (score 5):

Memory graph shows reference cycle

[image]There is definitely a retain cycle.

**Solution: It should `unowned` or `weak` to break the cycle**

```
struct X {
    unowned let propertyOfTypeY: Y
}

class Y {
    var propertyOfTypeX: X?

    deinit {
        print("Y deallocated")
    }
}

do {
    let y = Y()
    let x = X(propertyOfTypeY: y)
    y.propertyOfTypeX = x
}
```