# Swift - Holding closure reference leaks

Tags: swift

### Edit (after discussion):

It's a common practice in `SwiftUI` to have a `View (struct)` hold an `ObservableObject`. Since a `struct` is not a reference type, it's easy to forget that is holds one.

##### The questions should be really:

1. Can an indirect references cause a retain cycle?
2. Can a retain cycle involve a single pointer

The answer to both is *yes*.

1. struct -> class -> closure{struct.class}

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject
...
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Button("Action") {
            viewModel?.handler {
                // ViewModel is retained here through self:
                // (MyView.viewModel)
                self.someAction()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `SwiftUI`, it's not a good practice to 'pass yourself' to your `ViewModel`

2. Class holding an instance var pointing to itself
   (discussed here [How does ARC deal with circular linked lists when the external head reference is removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161606/how-does-arc-deal-with-circular-linked-lists-when-the-external-head-reference-is))

```swift
class A {
    var next: A
}
let a = A()
a.next = a // Retain cycle of an object to itself.
```

---

*(Original question)*

Why is holding a reference to a closure cause a memory leak even if the closure does not retain anything?

*(This started with a `SwiftUI` issue, but I'm not sure it's related really)*

So here's a simple Manager (`ViewModel`) that holds a closure.

```swift
class Manager: ObservableObject {
    
    private var handler: (() -> Void)?
    
    deinit {
        print("Manager deallocated")
    }
    
    func shouldDismiss(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        handler = completion
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.handler?()
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a view, using it:

```swift
struct LeakingView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var manager: Manager
    
    let shouldDismiss: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss") { [weak manager] in
            manager?.shouldDismiss {
                self.shouldDismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a `ViewController` activating the flow:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var popup: UIViewController?
    
    @IBAction func openViewAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let manager = Manager()
        
        let suiView = LeakingView(manager: manager) { [weak self] in
            self?.popup?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self?.popup?.dismiss(animated: true)
            self?.popup = nil
        }
        
        popup = LKHostingView(rootView: suiView)
        
        
        popup?.view.frame.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
        view.addSubview(popup!.view)
    }
    
}
```

When running this, as long as the manager is holding the closure, it will leak and the `Manager` will not get released.
Where is the retain cycle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is holding a reference to a closure cause a memory leak even if the closure does not retain anything?

Because the closure *does* retain something. It retains `self`.

For example, when you say

```
        manager?.shouldDismiss {
            shouldDismiss()
        }
```

The second `shouldDismiss` means `self.shouldDismiss` and retains `self`. Thus the LeakingView retains the Manager but the Manager, by way of the closure, is now retaining the LeakingView. Retain cycle!

This is why people say `[weak self] in` at the start of such closures.

Comment: In this case, if `shouldDismiss` is immutable, you can just capture that directly, instead of all of `self`.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "why people say `[weak self]`". I did _not_ say that this is what _you_ should say. I was just saying that it gets used a lot as a sort of catch-all way of solving the issue. It's way over-used.

Comment: Ok, but in this case, `self` is a `struct`, can we really 'retain' it, is it not just copied? And if so, what can we do (since we cannot use `weak` for a non reference var)?

Comment: @matt *I* know that, but you should explain it in your answer for OP

Comment: The question was where the retain cycle is. The question wasn't what to do about it.

Comment: Ok, so an retain cycle between an object and a struct is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632122/retain-cycle-between-class-and-struct That was really the main issue here

Comment: @bauerMusic Certainly. Why not?

Comment: _"Because the closure does retain something. It retains self."_ - Is it really 'self' that is being retained, or to pointer it holds? In that case, the `Manager` is retaining a pointer to itself by a `Struct`. There is only _one_ pointer here no?

Comment: I guess this is what is happening (simplified): `class A { var a: A? }`; `let a = A()`; `a.a = a`. An object retaining itself. It will not get released until `a.a = nil`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you might *not* want to use `[weak self]` pattern here. You are defining something that should happen ½ second after the view is dismissed. So you probably want to keep that strong reference until the desired action is complete.

One approach is to make sure that `Manager` simply removes its strong reference after the handler is called:

```swift
class Manager: ObservableObject {
    private var handler: (() -> Void)?
    
    func shouldDismiss(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        handler = completion
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.handler?()
            self.handler = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if the use of this completion handler is really limited to this method, you can simplify this to:

```swift
class Manager: ObservableObject {
    func shouldDismiss(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```swift
func shouldDismiss(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: completion)
}
```

All of these approaches will make sure that `Manager` does not keep any strong references beyond the necessary time.

Now, the caller can choose to use `[weak self]` if it wants (i.e., if it doesn’t want the captured references to even survive ½ second), but if you really want the “do such-and-such after it is dismissed”, it probably wouldn’t use `weak` references there either. But either way, it should be up to the caller, not the manager. The manager should just ensure that it doesn’t hang on to the closure beyond the point that it is no longer needed.

Comment: The takeaway is really that holding a closure in this settings is not a good practice. The code is just a sample, the ½ seconds just symbolizes some async task. In the original code (which I cannot share and did not originally wrote) there's a pointer to a closure that is called in too many places. The original reference cycle was caused by a `@State var` called inside a Manager's completion inside a `View` (like the sample provided). Looks perfectly innocent until things got leaky.

Comment: Yeah, I figured you may have simplified it for the sake of the question, which is why I didn't jump directly to the streamlined examples.

Comment: Just to be clear, a `ViewModel` cannot actually `retain` a `Struct` anymore than it can retain an `Int`, what it retains is its own (`ViewModel`'s) reference?

Comment: Correct, a struct cannot be retained.